# How can i get this border to wrap around my div?

Tags: html, css, tags, border

Hi guys i would like the border to surround my whole `<div id=wedding>` but it wont wrap around the image and the text within the `<div>`. Please help my code is below:

HTML:

```
<div id="Weddings">
        <img src="images/gallery/weddinggh.jpg">
        <br>
        <a href="gweddings">Click here to check out pictures of 
        <br> our past wedding cakes<a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#Weddings {
    padding: 2px;
    border: 1px solid;
}

#Weddings a:link {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
    font-size:16px;
    font-family: "footer";
}

#Weddings img {
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
}
```

Comment: You need to close your `a`, otherwise it looks ok: http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/AMfv2/4/

Comment: ^ That JsFiddle didn't change a thing lol...

Comment: It did for me.there's a border around the div which is what was required. **Quite simply the OP hasn't defined a border color**

Comment: There was always a border, the problem was it wasn't wrapping directly around the image and the text below and that's only because the width. He didnt say he didnt have a border because he does and he can see it lol he just needs it wrapping. Try reading first before answering.

Answer (score 2):

```
#Weddings {
padding: 2px;
border: 1px solid;
width:200px;
}
```

you just need to set a width to your div :)

Here's an example : http://jsfiddle.net/f4t2Z/

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a border color

```
#Weddings {
padding: 2px;
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

or whatever.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried

```
#Weddings img {
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Generally code-only answers with no comments or explanation are frowned upon. You can improve this answer by adding an explanation of why it might solve the problem.